# Capture disappearing API link and payload from browser

Tags: rest, web-services, web-inspector

I am trying to capture payload information and Endpoint link from a particular web site i am using, Since i don`t have any documentation i have to capture endpoint manually. 
i see Endpoint link is appears in web inspect for 3-4 seconds when i do any post request and disappears before i can capture all details.. is there any way i can delay endpoint visibility in browser and capture information?

This may not be programming question but this task mostly performed by programmer, Hence looking for answer in this site.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to resolve it.
From Chrome network option Check option-- > preserve Log 
[image]